# Linking user to project without direct relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to figure out how to do something.  I make an API call to retrieve a load of Projects.

```
$projects = APIHelper::returnRequestedProjects();
```

The API being called is on another server and what is returned is an array.  Within my own Laravel project, I have a database with my own users.  I do not model the projects against these users.  However, each product returned above however has a user_id, which matchesa user's id within my system.

What I need to do is obtain the user model for each project.  If I was dealing with a single project I could do something like this in my Controller

```
$user = User::where('id', $project->user_id);
```

As the API call returns an array of projects, I pass this directly to my view.  I would then do something like this

```
@foreach($projects as $project)

@endforeach
```

How would I go about though matching a projects user_id to a user within my system?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are getting a response from a remote server with an array of data you need to get User data for.

```
$projects = APIHelper::returnRequestedProjects();
```

Therefore, inside your controller method,

```
$ids = [];
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $ids[] = $project['user_id']; // Assuming the user_id is the id field
}

$returnArray = [];
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $returnArray[] = User::where('id', $id)->first();
}
```

Pass the return array into your view:

```
return view('example.view', ['returnArray' => $returnArray]);
```

And then inside the view...

```
@foreach($returnArray as $value)
    {{$value->id}}
@endforeach
```

EDIT: To answer the question in comments...

```
$returnArray[$project['id']] = User::where('id', $id)->first();
```

Inside your views, the returnArray keys are now the actual IDs of      projects you retrieved.

```
@foreach($returnArray as $projectId => $user)
    Project ID: {{$projectId}}, User ID: {{$user->id}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, thats helpfull.  The only issue I see is that I now pass $returnArray back to my view which has a list of users.  However, I am also passing projects back to my view.  How can I associate the user to the correct project?

Comment: Super easy. You can manipulate the array keys!

I am going to edit my original reply to make it look pretty...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
foreach($projects as $project) {
    $project['user'] = User::where('id', $project['used_id'])->first();
}
```